# Excel VBA - How to Populate Array from SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've been trying to write a piece of code that would allow me to query an SQL DB and use the returned values to populate a combobox.

The query runs fine when I ask it to return the values to the worksheet, however I don't want them there, I simply want to store them in an array to be used by the combobox.

Here's what I have so far...

```
Sub testQuery()
Dim varConn As String
Dim SQL As String
Dim test As String


Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents

varConn = "ODBC; DSN=Traceability DB;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX"

SQL = "Select Distinct ""Date"" from testtable"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=varConn, Destination:=Range("A1"), SQL:=SQL)
    .Refresh
End With

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

I'm not sure how to replace Range("A1") to an array.

Note: this is being used on the latest version of Excel for the MAC.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't really do much Excel programming, but doesn't Range("A1") refer to a single cell?   Should it be something like Range("A1:E15")?

Answer (score 1):

Save it in record set. Something like this:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select Distinct ""Date"" from testtable")
```

To access records in record set use `GetRows`
Something like this:

```
data = rs.GetRows(j)
```

and then loop through data.

Comment: I looked online and found some examples that define db as as: Dim db as Database
My problem is that this datatype is not available to me for some reason, anybody know why this may be?

Comment: I'm not a VBA expert, but seems like you do not have appropriate reference. What's the exact error?

Comment: Error: User Defined type not defined. I looked at my available reference and I have the following selected: Excel, Forms, and Office Object Library. The available ones are: OLE Automation, Solver, VBA Project, Chart 14 Type Library, Microsoft Graph, Powerpoint and Word Object Library, and Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/991207-user-defined-type-not-defined.html and this: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/211599-a97-dim-dbs-database-yields-error-user-defined-type-not-defined maybe soemthing will solve your problem